# Unable to insert background image on JSP file

Tags: html, jsp, background

I tried to insert background image on JSP (by eclipse), and the image file is correctly

inserted on the right folder(/WebContent)

however, the JSP file does not show background image.

please help me

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=euc-kr" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
<title>Login Page!</title>
</head>
<body BACKGROUND="Untitled.jpg">
<form action="loginCheck.jsp" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>0000000000000000000000000000</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>UserID :</td><td><input type="text" name="UserID"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>UserPW :</td><td><input type="password" name="UserPW"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>middle left :</td><td><input type="submit" name="Login"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>0000000000000000000000000000</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check spelling on the filename (for example, you used a capital letter)? Is the image located in the same directory as the JSP-file is delivered (means both are in */WebContent*)? Are the user rights set correctly? Maybe you have to use `chmod` in addition. And as a note: Instead of the `background`-attribute you should use the CSS `background`-property. The HTML-attribute is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

try this css codes

```
    <div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
         <img src='untitled.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
     </div>
```

the values of the height and width can be adjusted depending on the size you wish to obtain.